How to create a Junit test case in Intellij IDEA?

I need to set up a JUnit test case for a Java project. How can I manually add a test folder to your project structure and write a JUnit test case to execute and view the results? Can anyone provide any guidance on this?

If you press shift + t should show up a popup about create test for the current class, either way you can create manually your test package and add it in the properties of the project.

I pressed shift + t but nothings happening just t is getting typed.

Depends probably on the OS. When the cursor is on the class name either use alt+return/option+return (macOs) or alt+del/cmd+N, or just rightclick the class name and unter generate you find the option to create a test.
You could for example put your existing code inside a main package and create inside src a test package. And put your tests inside this package. For example:
src/main/AttendClass
src/test/AttendClassTest

if you, for example have under main, new packages in the feature.
you could do
src/main/newpackage/NewClassTest
src/test/newpackage/NewClassTest

